My media is not being uploaded to Pinterest using API
I have created a workflow to create pins on Pinterest using API but the media status is always registered and not failed or succeeded.
Is there something else i need to do after making request to upload media or should i just wait insane amount of time for it to complete.
The upload request is
curl --location --request POST 'https://api.pinterest.com/v5/media' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer <token>' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "media_type": "video",
    "upload_url": "amazon s3 video link",
}'

After making the request and getting the media ID, i make this call :
curl --location --request GET 'https://api.pinterest.com/v5/media/{media_id}' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer <token>'

And the result is always :
{
    "media_id": "5360253467671709010",
    "media_type": "video",
    "status": "registered"
}

Even 30 minutes after the status is still registered and therefore i cannot create a Pinterest PIN without it being done.
I have tried reading and following all the steps in the pinterest documentation but there is nothing there that helps.
https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/content/content-creation/#Creating%20video%20Pins
Also my app is approved with standard access and ready for production.

"The upload request is" - that is not the upload, that is just registering your intent to upload a video. And why are you sending upload_url as a parameter? This is a value you will get back from the register endpoint, and then you need to make your next request - the one that actually uploads the video - to this upload_url.

wow, I didn't even notice that, maybe i was hoping the video upload was as simple as facebook where i just pass the url to the video and it will handle uploading i, but i completely missed that. That resolves this issue, thanks a lot @CBroe
